# how to test a stale link click (or link I can't get to) using capybara/rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, hyperlink, rspec, capybara

Artists cannot rate their own artworks

```
it "should display error if voting on own artwork", :js => true do
  sign_in
  visit "/upcoming"
  click_link "like_post_1"
  page.should have_content("Can't vote on your own artwork")
end
```

This was passing just fine.

However, I can't click on `like_post_1` anymore because I added a feature to prevent voting links from appearing next to your own artworks.

Does this mean I no longer need test coverage for this scenario because it's extremely rare that someone can click on a voting link for their own artwork?  Or should still have coverage to test the ajax response, because it's not tested anywhere else and it's possible for some stale page of links to somehow exist in a tabbed browser window.  If so... how do I test it if I cannot call `click_link`?

I could try to create a POST request to create the vote, but capybara doesn't support posts, and I can't test the ajax response that way...

Or is there a way to simulate tabbed browsing in capybara?

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS display:none or visibility:hidden for the own artwork instead of eliminating the link from the DOM. You might have to set

```
Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false
```

Another way is giving up Capybara and putting them into the controller/model spec. Controller/model spec might be a better place for the extremely rare case or safeguarding your app case.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

Use **sleep** function.

**sleep 10** use to wait process upto 10 seconds..

```
it "should display error if voting on own artwork", :js => true do
  sign_in
  visit "/upcoming"
  click_link "like_post_1"
  sleep 10
  page.should have_content("Can't vote on your own artwork")
end
```